# Exception in CloudWatch Log for AWS - S3 Access Denied

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The flow goes like this...

S3->SNS->SQS->Lambda->S3 in AWS.

I upload an Excel file with some data to S3 Bucket. When it is uploaded, an event will fire from S3 and then sends message to SNS. From SNS, a message is sent to SQS. SQS will now trigger the Lambda Function written in .NET 6.0. At last, Lambda will process the excel file and stores the processed output to the same S3 Bucket with different name.

In this I am able to go upto SQS. Now the messages are in Flight. When I check the Cloud Watch, I see the below `Access Denied` error...

[image: Access Denied]

How to rectify this error? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the log from CloudTrail...

```
{
"eventVersion": "1.08",
"userIdentity": {
    "type": "IAMUser",
    "principalId": "PRINCIPALID",
    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/userid999",
    "accountId": "111111111111",
    "accessKeyId": "AKIAUGBVTP5DDSSZLYFK",
    "userName": "userid999"
},
"eventTime": "2023-04-11T13:59:12Z",
"eventSource": "lambda.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "UpdateFunctionConfiguration20150331v2",
"awsRegion": "us-east-1",
"sourceIPAddress": "88.99.88.99",
"userAgent": "AWSToolkitPackage.VS2022/1.40.0.0 .NET_Runtime/4.0 .NET_Framework/4.0 OS/Microsoft_Windows_NT_10.0.22621.0 ClientId/65c4ccccccc0c0c9c733 ClientAsync",
"requestParameters": {
    "functionName": "MyLambda",
    "vpcConfig": {
        "subnetIds": [],
        "securityGroupIds": [],
        "ipv6AllowedForDualStack": false
    },
    "environment": {}
},
"responseElements": {
    "functionName": "MyLambda",
    "functionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:111111111111:function:MyLambda",
    "runtime": "dotnet6",
    "role": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/service-role/MyLambda-role-test",
    "handler": "AWSLambdaExcel::AWSLambdaExcel.Function::MyLambda",
    "codeSize": 6723236,
    "description": "",
    "timeout": 15,
    "memorySize": 512,
    "lastModified": "2023-04-11T13:59:12.000+0000",
    "codeSha256": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "version": "$LATEST",
    "vpcConfig": {
        "subnetIds": [],
        "securityGroupIds": [],
        "vpcId": "",
        "ipv6AllowedForDualStack": false
    },
    "environment": {},
    "tracingConfig": {
        "mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "revisionId": "111111-2737-1111-afb4-1111",
    "state": "Active",
    "lastUpdateStatus": "InProgress",
    "lastUpdateStatusReason": "The function is being created.",
    "lastUpdateStatusReasonCode": "Creating",
    "packageType": "Zip",
    "architectures": [
        "x86_64"
    ],
    "ephemeralStorage": {
        "size": 512
    },
    "runtimeVersionConfig": {
        "runtimeVersionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1-1::runtime:45f8a281bf9e1111111111111111111ca96fcdfc615f54dcf70554a9e5"
    }
},
"requestID": "3e33acd0-6190-41cb-8301-uujjhhhggg",
"eventID": "0e30d3e1-7777-8888-9165-9999999999",
"readOnly": false,
"eventType": "AwsApiCall",
"managementEvent": true,
"recipientAccountId": "11111111111",
"eventCategory": "Management",
"tlsDetails": {
    "tlsVersion": "TLSv1.2",
    "cipherSuite": "3333333333333333",
    "clientProvidedHostHeader": "lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
}
```

}

Comment: What are the IAM permissions in the `arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/service-role/MyLambda-role-test` role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your lambda function doesn't have the permissions to upload the file to the new bucket. If you want more information on the specific permission error, you should check out [Cloudtrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) and search for your lambda function to see the events that are generated.

Once you discover the permission that is needed, you can update the role that is attached to your lambda function to grant access to that bucket. Another thing to check is if the bucket permissions allow the lambda function. If it is in the same account, it should by default.

Comment: I am using the same S3 Bucket with Full Permission to the logged in User ID to send the Response output Excel file. Also, I am able to successfully run the Lambda Function locally in Visual Studio. The only thing I did is creating a new role for Lambda and for all other SNS, SQS, S3, I used logged in User ID.

Comment: Updated the Question with CloudTrail Log. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't tell us much. What does the lambda role contain for its permissions? You said that "all you did was create a new role for lambda" which gives us a good indication of where the problem lies.

Comment: Now I got your point. But could you please tell me, what are the permissions I have to give in IAM for that Lambda Role? So that, I would use the least permissions here :)